# Does MySQL's LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE not work with CSV files?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to import a csv file into a MySQL database using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE. For some strange reason, it does not import every record. Out of 300 records, it only imported 165 records at random. This is my code:

```
mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/my/directory/public_ftp/incoming/clubperformance.csv' INTO TABLE `my_wonderful_table` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES(`Column1`, `Column2`, `Column3`)") or die(((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));
```

There is no error message generated by the code. I am not in control of the format or structure of the csv files so if the files are flawed in some way, I would appreciate it if you could show me an alternative & reliable way to import the file via PHP. Each file has got approximately 300 records & I'll be importing approximately 20 files a day.

I'm quite sure that my database structure is ok because I successfully imported the same data into the same database after first converting the csv file into a text file.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample from the CSV file?

Comment: I could send it to you personally but I prefer not to display the csv file here for personal reasons...

Comment: You can post the a same structured/example csv with personal details stripped or mock content. Also, what happens if you run the `LOAD DATA` command outside of PHP code such as command line or through a console?

Comment: This is usually caused by `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` or `[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY` or `LINES TERMINATED BY` not precisely matching what's in the file.  Examine what was actually loaded and examine the lines immediately surrounding them, perhaps with a hex editor, and a pattern should emerge.  Since this is a php quoted string, you might need to escape the backslash in `LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'`.